# dynamic calculation of simple math expression

Tags: php

We are taking simple math expression as inputs from user and want to evaluate it. Total number of fields are also dynamic. Each field contains the specific css class as per their index. For example, 1st field has css field "col1", 2nd field has "col2" and so on.

Users gives us input in the form of

> "col5 = col4 * col3"

We are converting it to

> jQuery(".col5").val(jQuery(".col4").val() * jQuery(".col3").val())

using str_replace function. To do so, we need to do loop for total no of fields. (below is php code example)

```
for($colLoop = 0; $colLoop < $total_cols; $colLoop++){
        $formula = str_replace("col$colLoop","parseFloat(jQuery('.col$colLoop input').val())", $formula);
      }
```

This works but we are looking for some proper solution as it's loops unnecessary for all fields. Is it possible using some other methods? Let us know

Comment: Have a look at `preg_replcae()`

Comment: Provide your html code. Show simple example with two-three classes and their expected outputs.

Comment: Hi, We have already provided code of how we are currently doing. Please check. Thanks

Comment: We know about preg_replace and preg_match but we are not able to find it our use. Can you please elaborate more. Thanks